# How to send Android GPS coordinates to MySQL every 5 seconds

Tags: android, mysql, gps

I'm trying to get GPS coordinates from Android and send it to MySQL database.

Everything is working well, but the program enters into unlimited loop :because I used While (true) to updates the GPS coordinates and send it to Database every 5 seconds.

How can I avoid the loop and send the coordinates into database every 5 seconds.

here is my code:

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnShowLocation;

    GPSTracker gps;
    double tmplat=0;
    double tmplong=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        while (true)
        {
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                String lat=String.valueOf(latitude);
                String lon=String.valueOf(longitude);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", lon));
                try {   
                    CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://plangsm2012.site40.net/new/check.php", postParameters);
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                }
                tmplat=latitude;
                tmplong=longitude;  

            }

            else{
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer for this problem.

```
private void time() {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

             gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                String lat=String.valueOf(latitude);
                String lon=String.valueOf(longitude);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", lon));
                try {   
                    CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://plangsm2012.site40.net/new/check.php", postParameters);
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                }
                tmplat=latitude;
                tmplong=longitude;  

            }

            else{
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, 5000); // 5 sec

}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think Handler().postDelayed is used to delay the execution of the code, but how can I loop the execution every 5 seconds

Comment: NameValuePair is Deprecated In Newer versions of android.

Answer (score 0):

In your locationlistener, fill your bean and post, as follows:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    myLocation.setLatitude(Double.toString(arg0.getLatitude()));
    myLocation.setLongitude(Double.toString(arg0.getLongitude()));
    myLocation.setTimestamp(arg0.getTime());
    myLocation.setUserId(Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    if (new DateTime(arg0.getTime().minusMinutes(5) > new DateTime(oldTime)) 
        postToRemote(myLocation);
}
```

myLocation is a [bean](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138795.html) containing properties for latitude, longitude, timestamp, and the device id, erroneously called userId for legacy reasons.

As for posting every 5 seconds, you need to record the time it posted and compare it to the current time before the post call as in the if statement above.